# Why won't top work with a negative calc value?

Tags: css

Applying

```
top : - 32px;
```

Works, but the following does nothing :

```
top : calc(8px - 50%);
```

I'd like to have the property be dynamic as the goal is vertically aligning a div in a parent div that has a variable height.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you provide your html/css? I think you're going about this the wrong way presently. For example, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/rjab9ann/) where you can have a child that will always stay in the center

Answer (score 1):

It works fine.

```css
div#outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: visible;
}

div#inner {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(8px - 50%);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```